# Send the logs prestashop to kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, prestashop, kibana

**How i can send the logs of my application which is in prestashop to kibana?
 as you know prestashop save the logs in database. Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these approachs :

- Using the official framework ([elasticsearch-php](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html)) you create a single file script that communicates directly with your ES cluster and sends the data via a direct query to the db :

  select * from ps_log where date_add > xxxx

that you can implement in your script.

- You create a daily CSV log of the table data with a PHP script and "ingest" this log to your elasticsearch cluster using [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/logstash).